# How to override CSS slider animation -- pure CSS slider with NAV?

Tags: html, css, slider, css-animations

I'm trying to create a pure CSS automatic animated slider with NAV buttons. Slider animation and navigation works great if they are by themselves, but when I combine them, the automatic animation overtakes the navigation system, and I can't move between slides using the navigation buttons. How can I stop the animation from overpowering navigation so that I can move between slides while still keeping the automatic scroller? Here's my code

```css
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

figure p {
  position: absolute;
}

figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 400%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  transition: left 2s;
  animation: 20s slidy infinite;
}

.slider figure .slide {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.slider figure img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.button_container {
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider_button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0px 15px;
}

#slide-1:target~.slide_container {
  left: 0%;
}

#slide-2:target~.slide_container {
  left: -100%;
}

#slide-3:target~.slide_container {
  left: -200%;
}

#slide-4:target~.slide_container {
  left: -300%;
}

@keyframes slidy {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  21% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  46% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  71% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  96% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <span id="slide-1"></span>
  <span id="slide-2"></span>
  <span id="slide-3"></span>
  <span id="slide-4"></span>

  <figure class="slide_container">
    <div class="slide">
      <p>Test1</p>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300?text=1" class="slider_image">
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <p>Test2</p>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300?text=2" class="slider_image">
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <p>Test3</p>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300?text=3" class="slider_image">
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <p>Test4</p>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300?text=4" class="slider_image">
    </div>

  </figure>

  <div class="button_container">
    <a href="#slide-1" class="slider_button"></a>
    <a href="#slide-2" class="slider_button"></a>
    <a href="#slide-3" class="slider_button"></a>
    <a href="#slide-4" class="slider_button"></a>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

On idea, is to define the same animation 4 times and on click you activate the needed one with a delay to show the target image and then the slider will continue to run automatically. But you will not have a transition when changing the image. Not sure if it's doable with your configuration.

```css
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

figure p {
  position: absolute;
}

figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 400%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  transition: left 2s;
  animation: 10s slidy infinite;
}

.slider figure .slide {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.slider figure img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.button_container {
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider_button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0px 15px;
}

#slide-1:target~.slide_container {
  animation: 10s slidy1 infinite;
}

#slide-2:target~.slide_container {
  animation: 10s slidy2 infinite -2.5s;
}

#slide-3:target~.slide_container {
  animation: 10s slidy3 infinite -5s;
}

#slide-4:target~.slide_container {
  animation: 10s slidy4 infinite -7.5s;
}

@keyframes slidy {
  0%,21%,100% {left: 0%;}
  25%,46% {left: -100%;}
  50%,71% {left: -200%;}
  75%,96% {left: -300%;}
}
@keyframes slidy1 {
  0%,21%,100% {left: 0%;}
  25%,46% {left: -100%;}
  50%,71% {left: -200%;}
  75%,96% {left: -300%;}
}
@keyframes slidy2 {
  0%,21%,100% {left: 0%;}
  25%,46% {left: -100%;}
  50%,71% {left: -200%;}
  75%,96% {left: -300%;}
}
@keyframes slidy3 {
  0%,21%,100% {left: 0%;}
  25%,46% {left: -100%;}
  50%,71% {left: -200%;}
  75%,96% {left: -300%;}
}
@keyframes slidy4 {
  0%,21%,100% {left: 0%;}
  25%,46% {left: -100%;}
  50%,71% {left: -200%;}
  75%,96% {left: -300%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <span id="slide-1"></span>
  <span id="slide-2"></span>
  <span id="slide-3"></span>
  <span id="slide-4"></span>

  <figure class="slide_container">
    <div class="slide">
      <p>Test1</p>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300?text=1" class="slider_image">
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <p>Test2</p>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300?text=2" class="slider_image">
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <p>Test3</p>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300?text=3" class="slider_image">
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <p>Test4</p>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300?text=4" class="slider_image">
    </div>

  </figure>

  <div class="button_container">
    <a href="#slide-1" class="slider_button"></a>
    <a href="#slide-2" class="slider_button"></a>
    <a href="#slide-3" class="slider_button"></a>
    <a href="#slide-4" class="slider_button"></a>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Its a nice approach. But this one has a problem. for example if you navigate to any slider it will navigate to the correct slide. but after the next transition, you cannot navigate to the same slide unless you go to some other slide.

Answer (score 0):

@TemaniAfif beat me to it!
 Still I did the leg work to make it functional so here is the working snippet with the 5 keyframes (1 for the default and 1 for each slide with reorganised transform to make it work). Though as Termani said there is no transition when switching animation) :

```css
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

figure p {
  position: absolute;
}

figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 400%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 2s;
  animation: 10s slidy infinite;
}

.slider figure .slide {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.slider figure img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.button_container {
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider_button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0px 15px;
}

#slide-1:target~.slide_container {
  animation: 10s slidy1 infinite;
}

#slide-2:target~.slide_container {
  animation: 10s slidy2 infinite;
}

#slide-3:target~.slide_container {
  animation: 10s slidy3 infinite;
}

#slide-4:target~.slide_container {
  animation: 10s slidy4 infinite;
}

@keyframes slidy {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  21% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-25%);
  }
  46% {
    transform: translateX(-25%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  71% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-75%);
  }
  96% {
    transform: translateX(-75%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes slidy1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  21% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-25%);
  }
  46% {
    transform: translateX(-25%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  71% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-75%);
  }
  96% {
    transform: translateX(-75%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes slidy2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-25%);
  }
  21% {
    transform: translateX(-25%);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  46% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-75%);
  }
  71% {
    transform: translateX(-75%);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  96% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-25%);
  }
}

@keyframes slidy3 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  21% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-75%);
  }
  46% {
    transform: translateX(-75%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-0%);
  }
  71% {
    transform: translateX(-0%);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-25%);
  }
  96% {
    transform: translateX(-25%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}

@keyframes slidy4 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-75%);
  }
  21% {
    transform: translateX(-75%);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  46% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-25%);
  }
  71% {
    transform: translateX(-25%);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  96% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-75%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <span id="slide-1"></span>
  <span id="slide-2"></span>
  <span id="slide-3"></span>
  <span id="slide-4"></span>


  <figure class="slide_container">
    <div class="slide">
      <p>Test1</p>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300?text=1" class="slider_image">
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <p>Test2</p>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300?text=2" class="slider_image">
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <p>Test3</p>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300?text=3" class="slider_image">
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <p>Test4</p>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300?text=4" class="slider_image">
    </div>

  </figure>

  <div class="button_container">
    <a href="#slide-1" class="slider_button"></a>
    <a href="#slide-2" class="slider_button"></a>
    <a href="#slide-3" class="slider_button"></a>
    <a href="#slide-4" class="slider_button"></a>
  </div>


</div>
```

Also it's not perfect because when you click on the "1" button for example and the animation restart (2, 3, 4..), if you click again on the "1" .. nothing happen (because it doesn't switch animation).

Comment: click on slide 2 and wait till it animate to next slide. click again and see what happens

Comment: Yes I edited my post about it at the same time you were commenting ;)